# Angular 2 RC4 Route Guards service injection

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having an issue with the Route Guards in Angular 2.  It seems like the Guard is getting a separate instance of my authentication service.

I'm attempting to setup my guard similarly to the Angular documentation:

The Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router:Router,
            private authenticationService:AuthenticationService) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    isLoggedIn:boolean = false;

    login() {
        return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
    }

    logout() {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

The Login:

```
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private router:Router,
                private authenticationService:AuthenticationService) {
    }

    login() {
        //TODO: Flesh out actual authentication
        this.authenticationService.login()
            .subscribe(() => {
                if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn) {
                    this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
                }
            });
    }
```

The Bootstrap:

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {RouterConfig, provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";

//Components
import {MainComponent} from "./main/main.component";

//Routes
import {LoginRoutes, AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDERS} from "./routes/login.routes";
import {DashboardRoutes} from "./routes/dashboard.routes";
import {AdministrationRoutes} from "./routes/administration.routes";

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...LoginRoutes,
    ...DashboardRoutes,
    ...AdministrationRoutes
];

//Providers
const ROUTE_PROVIDER = [
    provideRouter(routes),
    AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDERS
];

bootstrap(MainComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTE_PROVIDER
]);
```

The Login Routes:

```
import {RouterConfig} from "@angular/router";

import {AuthenticationGuard} from "../guards/authentication.guard";

import {AuthenticationService} from "../services/authentication.service";

import {LoginComponent} from "../login/login.component";

export const LoginRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full"},
    {path: "login", component: LoginComponent}
];

export const AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDERS = [
    AuthenticationGuard, AuthenticationService
];
```

In the `LoginComponent`'s `login()`, the `authenticationSerivce.isLoggedIn` is `true`.  However, when the redirect to the Dashboard happens, the Guard is triggered, and inside it, the `authenticationService.isLoggedIn` is `false`.

I'm sure I'm just missing something in the dependency injection, but I can't figure it out nor see any difference in what I'm actually doing vs. the tutorial/documentation stuff.

Comment: Show your bootstrap function.

Comment: I added them to the OP

Comment: Everything seems good till now. Hard to catch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holy crap, I just got it.  Declaring the Authentication Service as a provider in my `MainComponent` was creating a separate instance of the service since I had already declared it a provider in the `bootstrap`.  I took out the providers reference to it in the `MainComponent` and everything is working now!!